# Problem in Online DFS (Artificial Intelligence)

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm

I think there is some problem in Online-Depth-Search Algorithm because I am not seeing any recursive calls .
Here is the code from peter Norvig .
Please help me understanding this if it is correct or wrong .

```
function ONLINE -DFS-AGENT (s′) returns an action

    inputs: s′, a percept that identifies the current state

    persistent: result , a table indexed by state and action, initially empty
    untried, a table that lists, for each state, the actions not yet tried
    unbacktracked , a table that lists, for each state, the backtracks not yet tried

    s, a: the previous state and action, initially null

    if GOAL-TEST(s') then 
        return stop
    if s ′ is a new state (not in untried ) then 
        untried[s′] ← ACTIONS(s′)
    if s is not null then
        result[s, a] ← s′
        add s to the front of unbacktracked[s′]
    if untried[s′] is empty then
        if unbacktracked[s′] is empty then return stop
        else a ← an action b such that result [s′, b] = POP(unbacktracked [s′])
    else 
        a ← POP (untried [s′])
    s ← s′
    return a
```

Comment: I don't have the book right now, but recursive calls are not the only way of implementing recursion. One can also store the information from current level i in a stack, move down to a recursive level i + 1, compute the result of level i + 1, and then pop the information from level i to compute the result of level i. Recursion in this code is being implemented through stacks.

Comment: Recursive calls can only be realized with a stack which is formulated in boolean logic. The commands are push and pop to interact with the stack. Because the push action is missing in the sourcecode, it won't work.

Comment: That's what I thought while dry running this program . I didn't got any idea how is it working ? But I need someone to explain me this if possible .

Comment: In the 4th edition of the book, there are many changes in the algorithm: http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/errata/aima-137.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You almost never need recursion, it is just convenient.

Using one or more stacks is an alternative for  DFS. Specifically the stack code above involves:

- Two tables of stacks: `untried` and `unbacktracked`
- Setting an entire stack: `untried[s′] ← ACTIONS(s′)`
- Pushing an element to a stack: `add s to the front of unbacktracked[s′]`
- Popping an element: `[s′, b] = POP(unbacktracked [s′])`
- Popping an element: `a ← POP (untried [s′])`

The reasons to use explicit stacks instead of recursions are:

- Easier to stop
- Dynamic memory is on many systems less limited than stack memory so you can handle larger graphs

However, the code is not clear - it uses POP and "add s to the front", which I assume is a PUSH.

Comment: But there is nothing like while stack is not empty. It will just check conditions do some push and pop and then return a .

Comment: It is intended to be called again and again (etc), until it returns stop (either due to GOAL-TEST or because both stacks are empty).

Comment: Thanks for the help .